Ubuntu 24.04 ending session
Recently my laptop (details below) running Ubuntu 24.04 has started logging me out without warning
The screen freezes for about 30 seconds, then goes blank, and finally I'm shown the login screen.
It's happened when running IntelliJ, or Audacity, or just browsing with Firefox
Sessions can go on for hours, or end after less than 30 minutes
What can I do to trace this issue?
There's three files in the /var/crash/directory

usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash (51MB binary file)
_usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.upload  (empty)
_usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.uploaded (37k text file - "ba98a3b4-182d-11ef-8b80-fa163ec8ca8c")

uname -a gives this
Linux my-laptop 6.8.0-31-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Apr 20 00:40:06 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsb_release gives this
No LSB modules are available.

System Details Report
Report details
Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              Dell Inc. Inspiron 17-7779
Memory:                                      16.0 GiB
Processor:                                   Intel® Core™ i7-7500U × 4
Graphics:                                    Intel® HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
Graphics 1:                                  NV118
Disk Capacity:                               1.1 TB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            1.34.0
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            Wayland
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-31-generic

** Update **
This is happening again. I can reproduce this every time with the latest release of eclipse. If I open Eclipse, and move a tab, then the screen freezes, eventually goes black, and then the login screen is displayed
So far, this is the only application that causes the logout

Please edit your question and add details about your hardware (CPU, RAM, free space on the partition Ubuntu is installed on) and add details whether your system has a swap file - if yes, which size - or not.

Look in /var/crash for .crash files that match the times of these desktop crashes (logouts)

Thank you, I've added the requested details

@JosephMcCarthy thx. Hardware looks ok, although the CPU is a bit old. However, you have enough RAM and disc space, so this should be the reason reason.

I don't understand @noisefloor, what should be the reason?

@JosephMcCarthy : sorry for the confusion - it should say "... so this should not be the reason". I forgot the write the "not" in my previous pst.

There was a warning in /var/syslog about missing files from ubuntu-advantage-tools, so I've removed and reinstalled it, and that seems to have resolved the issue

My ubuntu 24.04LTS XP64 Gateway laptop will occasionally suddenly freeze, go to black screen for a few minutes, then ends up at login screen - seems to happen if I don't let it 'stabilize' before over-tasking it like at boot up... have to give her extra time to 'settle-in' before zooming off w/browser. I'll watch HDD access light and wait until it finishes it's wake-up ~ play nice ;-)

I made a workaround changing the Exec attribute from my eclipse.desktop to this:
Exec=env GDK_BACKEND=x11 /my/home/to/eclipse/executable


Thank you! That has resolved the issue with tabs in eclipse
